# Renaming Files and Folders by removing text after a certain string

Tags: regex, powershell, file, directory, rename

I'm having trouble removing characters on **files and folders**. I need to remove all characters after `640`

**This is what i have**`

```
WW-459-1-6401HR5N6UJ

WW-478-2-6409Z7E6H98

XAC-3001-640GOGQ8ZHN
```

**This is what i need to get**

```
WW-459-1

WW-478-2

XAC-3001
```

Thanks

Comment: [Matching it is easy, `-640.*$`.](https://regex101.com/r/uPXuDG/1/) If you wish to replace it then you just need to figure out the powershell code for doing a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty specific request. If anything changes the script gets more complex. But string manipulation is pretty simple, and there's a lot of ways to do the same thing. Here's one example:

```
$str = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Path\To\WW-459-1-6401HR5.txt' | Select-Object -Property Name -ExpandProperty Name
$newStr = $str.Substring(0,$str.IndexOf("640")-1)
$newstr
$ext = $str.Substring($str.IndexOf("."),$str.Length - $str.IndexOf("."))
$ext
$finalStr = $newStr + $ext
$finalStr
```

Obviously you'll still need to add some logic to grab all the files and loop through them, but this takes care of the string manipulation that you requested.